# Topographical Elevations for Central Africa and Cameroon

Tags: data, dem, elevation, topography, africa

I am using QGIS and I have been faced with the problem of topographical maps. From searching online I could only find data for the United States. Google maps offers elevation contours, however I am looking for a solution for Central Africa, Cameroon that is more specific. I am also looking for any other resources that can equally show the different geographic basins in the target area.

Answer (score 3):

You might try downloading the 30m [SRTM](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) for your region and deriving the contours yourself. It's available through [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) for free. Contours can be generated with the Raster > Extraction > Contour tool in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Rob Skelly's suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155443), I would second using 30m SRTM data.

I know [Whitebox](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml) has a great tool for this that will download the SRTM files and process the DEM in one shot based on your area.

From here you can create contour or basins from the DEM.